# Como obter structs armazenado em um array/list como referencia no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, lista, referência

Eu estou usando um código similar a este:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public struct Teste {
    public int Numero = 0;
    public void SetNumero(int i) { this.Numero = i; }
}
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Teste>();
        
        // Inicializa o list
        list.EnsureCapacity(100);
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            list.Add(new Teste());
        }
        
        // Define o numero
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            list[i].SetNumero(i);
        }
        
        // Mostra o resultado
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i].Numero);
        }
    }
}
```

A minha ideia seria de inicializar a lista, definir o valor posteriormente (e conseguir alterar novamente no futuro) e depois exibir o resultado.

---

Porém, o resultado desse código é sempre "0 0 0 0 0 ...", como pode ver em https://dotnetfiddle.net/FnUmr2.

---

Eu consegui corrigir o problema fazendo:

```
        // Define o numero
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            var v = list[i];
            v.SetNumero(i);
            list[i] = v;
        }
```

Ou seja, isso confirma que, por algum motivo, ao fazer `list[i]` é retornado uma copia do valor imediatamente e isso parece impedir o `SetNumero` de aplicar a alteração no dado original. **Mas, acredito que isso não seja ideal.**

---

A forma acima exige uma copia adicional desnecessária (o `v = list[i]`).

**Há alguma forma de pegar o valor como referencia, algo como: `&list[i]`, por exemplo?**

*Eu tentei usar algo como `(ref list[i])` ou `&list[i]`, mas não funcionou.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma forma que parece melhor:

```
var list2 = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list);
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    ref var item = ref list2[i];
    item.SetNumero(i);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OYYuro). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/nmhplftfwo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Ref.cs).

Pegando o dado por referência resolve o que deseja, mas para isto precisa transformam a lista em Span para garantir o tempo de vida da referência e não ter insegurança.

Toda vez que alguém um um `SetNumero()` em C# um panda morre na China.

Comment: "Toda vez que alguém um um SetNumero() em C# um panda morre na China", se depender de mim, e do meu gerador de código, vai entrar em extinção. . Por enquanto, todas as linguagens estão usando o "padrão do Golang", mesmo que fique bizarro como neste caso. Mas enfim, essa parece ser a melhor opção e não tenho que trocar todos os `List<T>` para `T[]`.

Comment: `Por enquanto, todas as linguagens estão usando o "padrão do Golang"` Não, C# tem algo melhor. Na verdade nem sei o que é "padrão do Golang"`.

Comment: O código em C#, neste caso, é um código gerado. Eu escrevi o gerador para se comportar da forma mais proxma possível em todas as linguagens (ao invés de criar um código "mais adequado para cada linguagem").  Por exemplo, algumas linguagens como TypeScript é normal usar `algumaFuncao()` e outras `AlgumaFuncao()`. No Swift, C# e Kotlin existe os `get {}` e `set {}`, mas isso não existe no Zig, C, Go... Afim, meio que padronizei para uasr a mesma convenção do Go (resultando no `SetNumero`, e um panda a menos no mundo). 

Comment: Em C# na verdade nem deve existir um `SetPropridade`. As propriedades tem seus próprios getters/setters/ `Propridade { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente isso não ocorre com `array`, e somente com `List<T>` (e talvez outros), por algum motivo.

---

Então se não quiser copiar poderá simplesmente usar `new Teste[100];` e vai funcionar como o esperado:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new Teste[100];
        
        // Inicializa o list
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            list[i] = new Teste();
        }
        
        // Define o numero
        for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {
            list[i].SetNumero(i);
        }
        
        // Mostra o resultado
        for (var i = 0; i <list.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i].Numero);
        }
    }
}
```

*Pode testar em https://dotnetfiddle.net/SGHWaR.*

*Obviamente, agora terá que manter alguma informação sobre a capacidade e tamanho, já que não terá o `.Capacity` e o `.Count` (embora tenha o `.Lenght`).*